# Error on workflow task approval form

Tags: workflow, infopath, workflow-tasks-list

**Current setup:** When new infopath is created, it goes for admin approval. there is approval workflow running behind it. Task approval form, displays some important information from form submitted.

From last few days we started getting below error, when opening **task approval form**.

[image]

**ULS log shows:** Calculations exceeded the maximum stack depth. (User: \, Form Name:
Template, IP: ...

Task form does not contain any looping, nor there are any rules on its page load. form just contains some single line textboxes, displaying important information from request form.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved Now.

Root Cause: Approval task had hyperlink pointing to original request form. In order to open infopath in  browser we had concatinated "?OpenIn=Browser" at the end of URL.

During runtime due to some issue Persistent URL was getting generated for hyperlink instead of complete URL to request form. Persistent URL with text "?OpenIn=Browser" was giving mentioned error in this case.